# Link/bulletin color combination unfortunate

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I'm no professional graphic designer, but thin text, small print and primary contrast probably don't work well together :)

[image]

Comment: I agree! Also, the same Community Bulleting box is dark grey in meta, which makes it even less contrast-y.

Comment: I also just noticed that the event duration is grey on grey in meta. Eek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been changed, will be live after our next production build.

Answer (score 2):

Even more humbly than @Dominic, I'd like to propose a darker shade of the teal already in the colour scheme:

[image: Community Bulletin mockup with]

This is #137863, the same hue but way darker than the teal. Doesn't pop as much, but it's very legible. An even darker shade could be used for `a:visited` and `a:hover`, and the red for `a:active`.

Comment: The contrast is just far too subtle. On low quality screens it will be very hard to know what it says on first view. Also, it doesn't draw your eye at all, which I assume is the reason they made it red instead of white like the rest. I can read it fine and I think it looks OK, but it goes against what I assume to be its purpose and has accessibility issues (colour-blindness being the most obvious example).

Comment: It looks far more legible on my desktop screen than it did on my mobile. It's a little odd to me because my phone has a much higher resolution (445 PPI). This is an almost irrelevant comment, but the info is here if anyone wants it.

Answer (score 0):

If I may humbly suggest `#FFD943` as seen here:

[image: GD Colour suggestion][image: GD Colour suggestion]

for all to consider. :)

**How I got to this colour:**

**1.** I entered the background colour (`#5EC4A4`) into colorschemedesigner.com and turned the brightness and saturation all the way up and applied a slight increase in lightness until I was satisfied with the orange.

**2.** I tried a number of the different shades of orange shown here before taking the most comfortable one seen here with a red dot on it*:

[image]

**3.** I ran the orange through the magic colour machine again and looked at the accented analogic colour range seen here:

[image]

**`*`This is almost the exact same colour but when running through it again to show how I got the colour I couldn't tweak it to the exact same colour by hand. Very close though.**

I included how I got to this colour so that you can see it's clearly not a random choice.

Comment: Although I really like your way of coming up with an alternative colour, wouldn't it be weird to introduce a brand new colour to the design in this stage? I'd prefer a fitting colour that's already in the site's colour theme.

Comment: @Bakabaka I could be missing another but the only two colours I've noticed in the colour scheme are red and that greenish colour.  As it stands I don't think any colour in the scheme creates sufficient contrast against the green. I tried reds and oranges but due to the sort of dark shade of the green none worked. It could just be the 3rd colour used for adding very small elements. Using it on the bulletin sat perfectly well with the other colours. Which existing colour would you suggest?

Comment: a dark shade of the green, perhaps? And yes, I'm just spouting comment without putting as much time into this as you did :)

Comment: @Bakabaka Much like questions on the live site, I saw it as an opportunity to exercise my colour choosing skills in a small task. It took me longer to prep my answer than to find it lol. Your suggestion raises a good question; is it better to adjust colours in a scheme or introduce another? In retrospect, I think the yellow adds an element of friendliness to an otherwise strong and fairly serious colour scheme (red text scares me :P). It's just a suggestion to maybe give the SE designers a little less work. Do you think I should add a screenshot of the homepage with the yellow?

Comment: a screenshot might help, if you're willing to infringe upon Stéphane's job that much ;). You might, by the way, have a nice main-site Q there: 'Is it better to adjust colours in a scheme or introduce another?'

Comment: @Bakabaka I am trying to tread carefully and I hope Stéphane doesn't see it that way, I'm just trying to help and happy to be wrong. I'm thinking that question will probably need a use-case and the only one I can think of is this but I think that might be misconstrued and could descend into design-by-committee again. Any ideas for a different example? and if so, would you like to post it?

Comment: A splendid effort and kudos for the groundwork, but i am with @Bakabaka on this; adding a new colour not a good idea. It works, it looks good, but it introduces another level of – presumed – colour-coding.

Comment: @RandomO'Reilly Good point, that's the best reason not to so far, though they have essentially already created that new level they just used red instead. I'll leave it here anyway and see what happens. At least we've shared some of our thoughts for them to use if they deem appropriate.